# How to determine the HWND in an ATL message map with contained windows

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, hwnd, message-map

Let's say you're creating an ATL `CWindowImpl` class with one or more `CContainedWindow`s.  And then let's say you want to chain some of the `CContainedWindow`s' `ALT_MSG_MAP`s so that a couple windows share some base functionality in their window procedures.  But during those shared procedures, you're gonna want to know which window is receiving a given message.  ATL doesn't pass HWNDs in its message map handler functions.  So is there another way to determine which HWND you're dealing with?

Comment: It would be available as `m_hWnd` I think?

Comment: But wouldn't `m_hWnd` belong to the main class (the one deriving from `CWindowImpl`)?

Comment: I don't know for sure (not really an MFC expert) but I would have expected that the message handler would be called on the context of the window that received the message. Should be easy to verify anyway.

Comment: I believe you are meant to have different handlers in different alternative maps, so each handler just knows which window it's for. There doesn't appear to be any way to determine which map dispatched to a given handler. If you want two or more windows with the same behavior, implement a proper `CWindowImpl`-derived class for them, with its own message map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I'm not sure yet, but I think this might work:

```
#define MESSAGE_HANDLER_EX(msg, func) \
    if(uMsg == msg) \
    { \
        bHandled = TRUE; \
        lResult = func(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, bHandled); \
        if(bHandled) \
            return TRUE; \
    }
```

And then the handler function should have a signature like: `LRESULT HandlerFunc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL&)`.